# .deb installation won't run

Tags: ssh, webserver, sudo, web-hosting

I'm trying to install Wowza Software engine on my webServer, but it doesn't want go on.

When I connect to my host (a Debian system) remotely via ssh, I enter:

`su dpkg -i WowzaAndThaNameOfTheFile.deb`, nothing happens.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is this problem with this file only ? Meaning are you able to install other .deb packages ?

Comment: if not how can i do?
I have to contact the assistance of my hosting service?

Comment: If not then yes, ask your hosting service. They should be better equipped to answer your questions

Comment: Are you using `su` or `sudo`? You've tagged `sudo` but have `su` in your post, and also have the wrong syntax for `su` (to execute a command, you need `-c`)